# Github actions - how to deploy to remote server using SSH

Tags: ssh, github-actions

I've a staging server on DO.

I want to build & deploy my node app to it.

```
name: Build & Deploy
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v1.*.0'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create SSH key
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
          echo "$DO_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY" > ../github_do.key
          sudo chmod 600 ../github_do.key
          ssh-keyscan -H ${{secrets.DEPLOY_SERVER}} > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        shell: bash
        env:
          DO_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{secrets.DO_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY}}
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - name: Install Packages
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - name: Build artifacts
        env:
          DEPLOY_SSH_KEY_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/../github_do.key
        run: |
          yarn shipit production fast-deploy
```

What i've done is to generate a new SSH private & public keys.

The **private** key I've saved inside `DO_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY` github secret.

The **public** key I've added to `authorized_keys` on my staging server.

When the action is triggered, it fails on:

```
@ v***.256.0
Create release path "/home/***/***/releases/2020-03-0***-v***.256.0"
Running "mkdir -p /home/***/***/releases/2020-03-0***-v***.256.0" on host "***".
@***-err ***@***: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
'fast-deploy:updateRemote' errored after ***.32 s
Error: Command failed: ssh -i /home/runner/work/***/***/../github_do.key ***@*** "mkdir -p /home/***/***/releases/2020-03-0***-v***.256.0"
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I've solved it!
Apparently keys were protected with passphrase .

This is the whole process:

1. Genereate new keys

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user@remote-server.com" -q -N ""`

2. Update your remote server `authorized_keys`

   `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote-server.com`
3. Enter the remote server & run

`ssh-keyscan remote-server.com`

4. Copy the output to github secret (lets call it SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS)
5. Copy the private key to a github secret (lets call it SSH_PRIVATE_KEY)

In your workflow.yml file

```yaml
#workflow.yaml
...
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create SSH key
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
          echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ../private.key
          sudo chmod 600 ../private.key
          echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        shell: bash
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
          SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS: ${{secrets.SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS}}
          SSH_KEY_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/../private.key
```

Then you can use ssh with `ssh -i $SSH_KEY_PATH user@host`

Hope this will save few hours to someone :]

### Edit

#### Answer to comments (how to update github secrets)

In order add github secrets you have 2 options:

1. Via GitHub ui, [https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/settings/secrets/](https://github.com/%7Buser%7D/%7Brepo%7D/settings/secrets/)
2. Via GitHub API, I'm using [github-secret-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-secret-dotenv) lib to sync my secrets with my local `.env` file (pre action trigger)

Comment: though I like this approach, it seems to imply having the private key in the project. I'd suggest to add the gpg trick to avoid putting the plain key into the project as described in https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets

Comment: It is not in the source code, but saved inside github secrets

Comment: oh I see, can you please give some details about how you put/read from it there too please?, I ran into "invalid format" error when trying to use it

Comment: I've added this in my anwser

Comment: I'm getting `mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
##[error]No such file or directory`. Any idea why?

Comment: `mkdir -p ~/.ssh/` this command just creates a folders if not exists. I'm using it on a daily basis... it works. Maybe you are not using linux os?

Comment: It only happens in the GitHub Actions runner; however, if I checkout the repository beforehand, it works, although there is no need for it. Weird. Thanks for your response!

Comment: weird, try to write an empty file
```- name: Prepare env
           run: echo "" > ./test
           shell: bash```

Comment: @lewislbr You might need to add `uses: actions/checkout@v1` to the top of the list of steps

Comment: where did you set this ${{SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}  used here echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ../private.key  As it is different from ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}?

Comment: Pay attention, this is an env var that was populated from `secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`

Answer (score 19):

The answers of [felixmosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539317/felixmosh) and [Cas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175584/cas) but this feels like a better implementation. Rather than uploading your `known_hosts` file to the Github hosted runners just populate the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on runtime. More felxible as it might handle issues like IP changing. I tested it and it worked for me.

```yaml
- name: Write SSH keys
  run: |
    install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ssh-keyscan -H host.example.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Or, even better,

```yaml
- name: Write SSH keys
  run: |
    install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    host='host.example.com'
    hosts="$(dig +short "$host" | grep -v '\.$' | sed -z 's|\n|,|g')$host"
    ssh-keyscan -H "$hosts" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This ensures that all ips of the host are recorded in `known_hosts`.

Just replace `host.example.com` and you are good to go.

Comment: I see a problem that by generating the known_hosts it bypasses the security that you have verified the host so that you would be unaware if the host was not the same box. Perhaps using `HostKeyAlias` in SSH config would be a solution: https://serverfault.com/a/895661

Comment: [@Cas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175584/cas), I read the serverfault.com [thread](https://serverfault.com/a/895661). Not sure why the author used both `host` and `HostKeyAlias` when his suggestion is to use `HostKeyAlias`. Will something like `echo "HostKeyAlias host.example.com" > .ssh/config` work or not? Or I need to use both `host` and `HostKeyAlias`?

Comment: Both would be required since`Host` directive denotes a new section or directive for ssh config with option `HostKeyAlias` for that hostname.
However looking again at this perhaps `CheckHostIP no` is more straighforward

Comment: Then should I suggest `host myserver.example.com
HostKeyAlias myserver.example.com` in an edit?

Answer (score 18):

felixmosh's answer was useful but I managed to simplify it further using  `id_rsa` that will be automatically used by `ssh` and the secrets will be substituted without needing intermediary env vars:

```yaml
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
      - name: Create SSH key
        run: |
          install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          echo "${{ secrets.SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS }}" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - name: Deploy with rsync
        run: rsync -rav --delete build/ user@host:/
```

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of troubleshooting, I finally resolved the issue with automating code deployment using GitHub Actions. Below is the script that you can use by replacing the environment variables with your own.

```
run: |
      which ssh-agent || (sudo apk update && sudo apk add openssh-client)
      which rsync || (sudo apk update && sudo apk add rsync)
      mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      chmod 700 ~/.ssh
      touch ~/.ssh/private.key
      touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private.key
      echo -e "${{ vars.DEV_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/private.key
      # Append keyscan output into known hosts
      ssh-keyscan ${{ vars.DEV_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - run: |
      eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      ssh-add ~/.ssh/private.key
      echo "Deploy to dev environment"
      rsync --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync --delete -avuz --exclude=".*" ./docker-compose/docker-compose-prod.yml ${{ vars.REMOTE_USER }}@${{ vars.DEV_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS }}:$BASE_DEV_SERVER_PATH/docker-compose-prod.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I arrived at:

```
name: SSH Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Configure SSH
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.9.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_KEY }}

      - name: Git Pull
        run: |
          cd ${{ github.workspace }}
          ssh-keyscan -t rsa ${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          ssh ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }} "cd ${{ secrets.REPO_PATH }} && git pull origin main"
          echo "Successfully pulled repo."

      - name: Check Nginx configuration
        run: |
          echo "Checking nginx config"
          ssh ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }} "sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -t 2>&1"
          echo "Nginx configuration check completed."

      - name: Restart Nginx service
        if: success()
        run: |
          ssh ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SERVER_IP }} "sudo /bin/systemctl restart nginx"
          echo "Nginx service restarted successfully"
```

If anyone has any notes or comments about security and hardening it would be greatly appreciated. Sharing my solution as I thought it might help someone. Some of the answers here seem overly complicated.